# Is Office.InterOp still working after migration to O365

Tags: vb.net, office365, interop

I need your help on a generic question. I am using Visual Studio 2012 to develop my Windows Forms Application that is running only on my machine locally to support my work. I have Windows10 and Office2016 installed. My Application interacts with MS Access (via System.Data.OleDb) and Outlook+Excel via Office.InterOp. Fine.

Today I received the information that our Company is rolling out Office365 and I started researching how this could impact my development work. I am not a programmer (more business) but always try to teach myself. But in this case I have no clew what all that means. I read about registering my Application before I connect to Outlook, Outlook REST API and many other things.

So my questions are:

1. Will my Application work the same way after migrating to Office365 (InterOps) ?
2. Is there a good tutorial out there that helps me getting started?

I really appreciate any help and guidance on this. Have a great weekend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First what is yoy current version of Office you use ? Then do you know if your compagnie will move to office pro plus ? (I suppose yes)

Even if you pass to Office ProPlus  the interop will still work, you should after starting to move you app using Graph API, but this API is to interact with the Office 365 data, not the Office App, it's in this case you register your app o  the Azure Active Directory to have the right to use Office data

Comment: Thanks Mary for your feedback. We are currently using Office 2016 and yes, we are moving to Office Pro Plus. Regarding Graph API I would like to have some more insight. My App is only used by me and is only dealing with local files. But you mention Office data. My App is also reading my Outlook mails. So via Office.InterOp my app loops through my mail items and puts filtered information into an Access Database. Would that mean, I have to use Graph API?